# jquery - validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I make a simple validation plugin, that return false if input fail validation, the problem is this plugin only works with one input at a time. I want it to work with all input at the same time.

the code

```
$.fn.validate = function(options){
    var defaults = {
        required:true,
        minChar:0,
        maxChar:0
    },
    o = $.extend({},defaults, options);
    this.each(function(){
        var $this=$(this);
        var val = $this.val();
        if(o.required==true && val==''){
            return false;
        }else if(o.minChar>0 && val.length < o.minChar ){
            return false;
        }else if(o.maxChar>0 && val.length >o.maxChar ){
            return false;   
        }
        else{return true;}
    });
}
```

call

```
if(!$('#name').validate()){
    $('.name_inline_error').text('require name');
    return false;// return false to stop ajax form submiting
}

if(!$('#email').validate()){
    $('.email_inline_error').text('require email');
    return false;// return false to stop ajax form submiting
}
```

What the code will do is, if two inputs are empty, the plugin will only tell the name input error, only when the name input was validated, the form will tell the email input error. While, I want to see two errors at the same time.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use [the really awesome validation plugin at already exists](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)?

Comment: Thanks I rather make my own than reading lengthy document and redundant features.

Comment: With that logic, why are you using jQuery?

Comment: I use jquery to create jquery plugins :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return, you are skipping the rest of your function. Try something like this:

```
valid = true;

if(!$('#name').validate()){
  $('.name_inline_error').text('require name');
  valid = false;  
}

if(!$('#email').validate()){
  $('.email_inline_error').text('require email');
  valid = false;
}

return valid;
```

(+1 to Matt Ball's comment, however -- rolling your own on this one is going to take a long time.)